# jsdom and script tags with relative paths

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, jsdom, chai

I have some single page demos like this one here:  http://notjs.org/examples/forms/formmode_demo.html

I thought, wow, it would be super awesome if could write some tests in my existing mocha chai badness setup to test the examples directly like so:

```
        example = 'forms/formmode_demo.html'

        describe "examples/#{example}", () ->
          before (done) ->
            loadExample example, () => done()

          it 'should load in full input mode', () ->
            window.$('input').length.should.equal 2

          describe "in full input mode", () ->
            it 'should have visible save', () ->
              window.$('button.success').is(':visible').should.be.true
            it 'should have visible cancel', () ->
              window.$('button.cancel').is(':visible').should.be.true
            it 'should not have put inputs on readonly class elements', ()->
              window.$('.readonly input').length.should.equal 0
            it 'should have input with author name', () ->
              window.$("[data-not_attr='name'] input:text").val().should.equal window.dataObject.name
```

If I could do that, then I'd never suffer that embarrassing, "your example x stopped working months ago" moment.

I got it to work but only with script tags in the page src'd from http:// urls.  It's not that effective of a test if I have to deploy the package to the server before testing.

The example page loads jquery, underscore and notjs and needs to in order to function as a standalone demo. It should also be able to function, and can with relative urls, from the local file system. I originally had the notjs script tag on the page point to a relative path, e.g.

```
    <script src="../../notjs.basics.js"></script>
```

instead of

```
    <script src="http://notjs.org/notjs.basics.js"></script>
```

But then notjs.basics.js is never loaded (window.Notjs == undefined in the test) and I don't see any error from jsdom.  I've tried setting documentRoot jsdom option but that didn't seem to work.

For reference, the loadExample method and the rest of my jsdom setup is here:  https://github.com/bee-hub/notjs/blob/master/test/testHelper.coffee

Thanks for any help and suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't documented anywhere that I can see, but the testLocal() function in test/jsdom/index.js in version 0.8.4 of jsdom provides a "url" option to jsdom.jsdom(…) that seems to accomplish much the same goal that you'd expect from a documentRoot option. Using it, I'm able to resolve relative script source paths from an HTML document on my local file system.

For what it's worth, "documentRoot" isn't mentioned in the documentation, either. Its use is [anecdotally endorsed in a github issue](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom/issues/99), so maybe it worked in an earlier version.

Don't forget that jsdom.jsdom(…) will load scripts asynchronously, so be sure to hitch your tests to a document ready event.

Good luck!